# Why am I getting this error when mysql2 is required in production only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mysql2

My gemfile has this line:

```
gem 'mysql2', group: :production
```

but I get this error when I run the command from the command line:
`rails r "puts Rails.env"`

```
/Users/cgunnels/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in `rescue in spec': Specified 'mysql2' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'mysql2'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord)
from /Users/cgunnels/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:174:in `spec'
from /Users/cgunnels/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
from /Users/cgunnels/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
from /Users/cgunnels/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/cgunnels/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
from /Users/cgunnels/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
from /Users/cgunnels/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
from /Users/cgunnels/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
from /Users/cgunnels/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:116:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
from /Users/cgunnels/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/cgunnels/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/cgunnels/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/cgunnels/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
from /Users/cgunnels/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/cgunnels/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/cgunnels/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/cgunnels/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
from /Users/cgunnels/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
from /Users/cgunnels/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/cgunnels/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/cgunnels/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/cgunnels/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/cgunnels/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
...
rest of stack trace
```

On a side note: I haven't been able to figure out why mysql2 won't install. I've tried a couple fixes per a stackoverflow search but no dice.

UPDATE:
I didn't mention, but I want to be in development environment.

Comment: Remove `group: :production` unless you do `Bundler.setup(:production)`.

Comment: I don't know what the answer to this question is but I just changed my Gemfile to read `gem 'mysql2', '> 0.4.4', group: :production` and it bundled just fine. My guess is that there is something wrong with one of the compile files.

Comment: That is odd, but good that you fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `rails r` without telling which environment to then Rails will use the `development` environment as a fallback.

You have three options:

1. Start Rails in the production environment

   ```
   bundle exec rails runner -e production "puts Rails.env"
   ```

   or
2. Install the `mysql2` gem in all environment by removing the `, group: :production` from the `gem 'mysql2'` line in your `Gemfile`.

   or
3. Update your `config/database.yml` to use `sqlite3` instead of `mysql2` in the development environment.

Comment: I want development. There is the

`group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'byebug'
end`

Comment: Then update your `config/database.yml` to use the `sqlite3` adapter in development instead `mysql2`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting the error exactly because when you are not in production there is no database driver.